# Cardano Core Node has high Tip Diff in gLiveView after upgrading node(s) to 1.34.1

Tags: stake-pool

After upgrading my nodes to 1.34.1, I noticed that the Tip Diff KPI in gLiveView began returning high 200+ results and the block propagation times increased by a couple seconds.  The relay nodes are running fine, no change in behavior.

In addition to the node upgrade, I did implement a firewall threat detection and blocking service called "SNORT" on my WAN.

I have attempted to reboot the nodes, but behavior remains.

Node version: 1.34.1
gLiveView version: 1.26

Overall, I feel that the relay and core nodes are operating fine but perhaps the issue is with gLiveView.

*NOTE*
The missed slot leader checks KPI did not change.  The value still show "favorable" data after upgrade just as it did before upgrade.

All help / information is very much appreciated.

Nick

Answer (score 0):

my 1.34.1 tip diff is showing regular metrics.

- How did you configure SNORT? Try to stop the service and see if kpi is returning back to normal.

If not

- Switch back to cardano-node 1.33.0 and see if kpi is returning back to normal.

Hope it helps

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion.  I did temporarily stop the SNORT service, so we will see over the next few days if the KPI values return to normal.  Thanks again!

Comment: In troubleshooting this issue further, it appears that reinstalling gLiveView on all nodes has resolved the issue.  I will continue to monitor the core node for a couple days before confirming as solution.

*NOTE* I have restored the SNORT service on the WAN
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

This issue has been resolved by reinstalling gLiveView to the latest version.  No issues are caused by the SNORT service on my firewall.

Thank you, Nick

Comment: nice to hear that